# Export to CSV with chineses caracters with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, csv

I tried:

```
$name = iconv("utf-8", "GB18030", $value["name"]);
```

- open in text and change encode
- import in excel while changing the encode

I'm doing that with PHP and JS:

My PHP code:

```
echo '"name";"sex";"language";"city";"province";"country";"account"';
foreach ($res_account as $value) {
echo "\n".$name.";".$value["sex"].";".$value["language"].";".$value["city"].";".$value["province"].";".$value["country"].";".$value["account"];
}
```

responseText is the data that I echo in the php:

```
var myCsv = request.responseText;
window.open('data:text/csv;charset=GB18030,' + escape(myCsv));
```

Also tried with charset="utf-8".

I always get something like: "%u6CD5%u56FD" in the csv.
In the MySQL base I have something like: "ä»£äºšç‘ž"
But when I echo them it's ok.

Comment: According to [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) docs, it looks like the second parameter is the output charset, have you tried changing that to `utf-8`?

Comment: @PatrickBarr Yes, same thing if I put utf-8 as second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to translate you chars from "%u6CD5%u56FD" to "\u6CD5\u56FD" and  JSON.parse() your result:

```
myCSV = myCSV.replace(/%/g, "\\");
myCSV = JSON.parse('"'+ myCSV + '"');
```

Comment: Will try it, come back later to tell you if worked. Thank you